# Form submit didnot working properly and return data

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement

I have a form and here is the code

```
<form method="post" id="dvs-upload-booking">
<input type="hidden" name="tcs_bulk_booking" value="true">
    <input disabled="" style="text-align: center;" type="text" id="1" name="1" value="1" required="">
    <input type="text" id="name_1" name="order[1][name]" value="Peter " required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="dvs-btn-upload"> 
</form>
```

This is my php code which I try to run when someone click submit

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST["tcs_bulk_booking"])) {
        echo "Yes, Data is set";    
    } else {  
        echo "No, Data is not set";
    }
?>
```

But when I click Submit button it still show "No, Data is not set" despite it need to show  "Yes, Data is set".
Please tell me what I did wrong

Comment: In your form tag do not specify action attribute

Comment: I want to run my php function run on same page

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @macthiem if the action attribute is missing, it uses the same page. This is more secure than adding the attribute and trying to fill it properly.

Comment: @aynber var_dump($_POST); return 
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: @miken32 thank you. that's my shortcoming

Comment: @HannahJames I ran the code on my computer. when I click Submit button it show "Yes, Data is set"

Comment: where is your action in the <form tag:

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it outputs "Yes, Data is set" when the button is clicked. Try clearing your browser cache or use the incognito mode to test. Or just close and reopen your browser